# Session not working in AWS server after setting domain name to ip address

Tags: php, session, amazon-web-services

This is the first time i am doing the deployment from my side and am new to AWS. I have a project deployed on Amazon AWS server for testing purpose. I have set the domain name as:
`https://staging.xxxxx.com`

I have a login page here where once the user logs in successfully i am setting the userId in the session and navigating the user to dashboard.

In the dashboard i have added a function to check whether session set with value of userId. If the session is not set then i am navigating user back to login page. This is to block the unauthorized access to site.

I am facing problem here. when i was working with the server before adding domain name to IP address wvwrything works fine. When i have added domain to the IP with https then the session is not working. What is the problem here with AWS? Am i missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

In Amazon there is 2 IP for Typically EC2 instance. One is the internal IP that can change every time you shutdown or reset the system and the other one is public IP (that you have to attach yourself) when you want to do stuff inside that machine you can referred to localhost but you should never referred to the internal IP. When you do stuff that related to the outside world you should use public IP which is a static IP and will not change.

Comment: I am not getting you. what do i have to do in order to make the session work here

Comment: Okay I can try to help you but first I need to know that you understand the difference between the IP that the world see and the internal IP ?!

Comment: The current hosting is over the external IP address. The internal IP you are talking about, i got it.

Comment: should adding localhost work in this case??? i came around several articles here. let me try